# Email Limits in salesforce

Tags: email, limits

could you say me the exact limit of

Single Email limit and mass email  limit  Of a enterprise Org

Single Email Limit and mass email limit Of a Professional Org

Single Email Limit and mass email  limit Of a Unlimited Org... I've

already read the document that they gave from salesforce for apex governor limits. i could not get the exact answer. kindly help to figure out this. please If you are posting a comment, as i am beginner, i kindly request you to please completely explain it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following resources will answer your question for [General Email Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_email_general.htm&language=en) and [Mass Email Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_email_mass.htm&language=en).

> Single Email limit and mass email limit Of a enterprise Org

500 for mass.

> Single Email Limit and mass email limit Of a Professional Org

250 for mass.

> Single Email Limit and mass email limit Of a Unlimited Org

1000 for mass.

Emails sent via Salesforce will contribute to the daily mass limit **except those sent to internal e-mails, including partner users**. The General Email limits include things like attachment sizes, for example, which have their own limits.

With regard to Single Email Limits, all I can find is that

> You can send 100 emails per *SingleEmailMessage.*

I imagine this is the same across all orgs as [this resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm) doesn't mention anything except that limit for all editions. **I could be wrong on this though.**

**Edit:**
[This resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008tFFIAY) should help you as to the difference between Single and Mass E-mails, as explained there:

> Single email in UI can be used by workflows, alerts and notifications etc, where as mass emails can be used in the UI to send mass emails to contacts and leads using a template.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...... now its clear..... Hope this would be right..... thnks again...

Comment: @Shakthi No problem. If this answer is satisfactory, don't forget to mark it as correct as it may help people in the future with similar questions.

Comment: Hey, I dont see any difference between single and mass email.. if there could you please mention how can we differentiate it??

Comment: @Shakthi please see my edit.